# Unable to Access User Object with fastify Adapter Using StrategyCreatedStatic for Authorization in NestJS

Tags: express, nestjs, passport.js, fastify

I'm using `StrategyCreatedStatic` from passport to create a custom authorization strategy in NestJS. In my implementation, I call `this.success(user, info)` at a certain point. My endpoint is protected with `@UseGuards(AuthGuard('myguard'))`.

According to the documentation, I should be able to access the authenticated user through req.user. However, I'm using fastify as the adapter, and my parameters are defined as `@Req() req: FastifyRequest`. I've tried debugging the req object, but I can't find any user information. It seems like the user object is not being populated.

Can someone help me understand how to properly access the authenticated user with fastify as the adapter while using `StrategyCreatedStatic` for authorization in NestJS? Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: When you log `req.user` do you get a value, or `undefined`? Is it just a typescript error you're running into or a runtime issue?

Comment: Ok. Yeah, casting req to any and accessing directly via req.user works..

Answer (score 1):

`FastifyRequest`, by default, does not have a `.user` property on it. You have two choices here for typing it though:

1. Use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to add your own types to fastify's

```js
declare module 'fastify' {
  interface FastifyRequest {
    user: YourUserType;
  }
}
```

2. Create a custom type that extends `FastifyRequest` and adds the new property to the extension.

```js
export type CustomRequest = FastifyRequest & { user: YourUserType };
```

Or if you prefer interfaces

```js
export interface CustomRequest extends FastifyRequest {
  user: YourUserType
}
```

Both lead to the same end result, though I prefer to go with the custom type as it means not mucking around with `d.ts` files and *usually* has a more consistent approach with other tooling, like jest.